# Label above bar is only showing about 50 candles back, then nothing

Tags: pine-script

I want to display a label above each bar. So I try this:

```
label.new(bar_index, high, style=label.style_none, text=str.tostring(bar_index))
```

But it only shows up on around 50 bars back and forward to the newest candle. All bars left of that shows no label at all. (See attached screenshot.)

Why does this not work? Did I miss some setting?

[Screenshot: Bars showing only on some candles](https://i.stack.imgur.com/I0O7q.png)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a default limit of 50 labels. You can modify it by using the `max_labels_count` argument within `indicator()` with a maximum of 500 labels.

https://www.tradingview.com/pine-script-reference/v5/#fun_indicator

Comment: Thank you! Worked perfectly. I see now there is a reference to it in the documentation, but it was difficult to find.